# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error

Tags: cache, log, core-config-data, system-config, simplexml

I am having problem with Magento log

There are many log that say **simplexml_load_string (): parser error**. I have spend 4H to find the issue and finally got the issue.

Issue with Magento cache if Configuration cache is enable magento log entry for **simplexml_load_string error**.

can you suggest me how to fix this issue **without disable cache**

**error log:**

```
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : error parsing attribute name  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): l/&gt;&lt;specificcountry/&gt;&lt;debug&gt;0&lt;/debug&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;all  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : attributes construct error  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): l/&gt;&lt;specificcountry/&gt;&lt;debug&gt;0&lt;/debug&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;all  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag all line 88  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): l/&gt;&lt;specificcountry/&gt;&lt;debug&gt;0&lt;/debug&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;all  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : expected '&gt;'  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;debug&gt;0&lt;/debug&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;allwed_methods&gt;2DA&lt;/all  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: ups line 88 and all  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;debug&gt;0&lt;/debug&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;allwed_methods&gt;2DA&lt;/all  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: carriers line 88 and ups  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): owmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;allwed_methods&gt;2DA&lt;/allwed_methods&gt;&lt;/ups&gt;  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : error parsing attribute name  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ccountry&gt;IN&lt;/specificcountry&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;free_shippi  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : attributes construct error  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ccountry&gt;IN&lt;/specificcountry&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;free_shippi  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag free_shippi line 88  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ccountry&gt;IN&lt;/specificcountry&gt;&lt;showmethod&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;free_shippi  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 88: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: default line 2 and carriers  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): od&gt;0&lt;/showmethod&gt;&lt;sort_order/&gt;&lt;free_shippi~g_threshold/&gt;&lt;/matrixrate&gt;&lt;/carriers&gt;  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 128: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: config line 1 and default  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): st.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&lt;/remindermessage&gt;&lt;/ipsecuritymaintetance&gt;&lt;/etipsecurity&gt;&lt;/default&gt;  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 128: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): st.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&lt;/remindermessage&gt;&lt;/ipsecuritymaintetance&gt;&lt;/etipsecurity&gt;&lt;/default&gt;  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have invalid config.xml or system.xml file somewhere. maybe custom module you recently installed has it.

ssh to server then:

1. ```
   cd magento_root
   ```
2. ```
   find app -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'showmethod' {} \;
   ```

showmethod I took from this line:

> 2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
>   Entity: line 88: parser error : error parsing attribute name  in
>   /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line
>   383 2016-12-26T10:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():
>   l/><specificcountry/><debug>0</debug><showmethod>0</showmethod><sort_order/><all
>   in /var/www/html/bookyourcatalog/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 383

once you find XML check it for validity, you can use online xml validator or just scan through it and you will find mismatched or missed opening or closing tag.

repeat this operation for every log error line.

Comment: I will try it.but what is relation with cache because if i disable cache then warnings are hide

Comment: if you disable cache magento doesn't read modules .xml files.